# LINQ on a LinkedList - iterate over LinkedListNode<T>, not T

Tags: .net, linq, linked-list

I'm having a problem understanding how to do something in LINQ.

I have a linkedlist, the type of the object doesn't matter. What does matter is that I want to do something in a `Where()` based on the relationship between the current object *and the next one in the list.*

Why can't I do something like:

`linkedlist.Where(n=>a_function(n.Value, n.Next.Value))`?

What is the syntax to do this, if it's even possible? The type inference system seems to insist that I want the lambda argument to be `T`, not `LinkedListNode<T>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll have to write new iterator for linked list to do that. Something like

```
public static class LinkedListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> EnumerateNodes<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
    {
        var node = list.First;
        while(node != null)
        {
            yield return node;
            node = node.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

so you can use

```
linkedlist.EnumerateNodes().Where(n=>a_function(n.Value, n.Next.Value))
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job nicely. I'm a bit disappointed that there's no functionality for this out of the box. I would guess that you could create quite a lot of horrible endlessly repeating loops with this sort of thing, so that's one reason it might not feature. I'm wondering whether what I'm doing is a smell, if I have to kludge it like this.

Comment: I'm trying to do this, I used your method to convert my LinkedList to: IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<myObject>> and I get "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions"... Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue doesn't have much to do with type-inference; `LinkedList<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` , not an `IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>>`. Additionally, there isn't a *direct* way to get a sequence of `(current, next)` tuples, so you'll have to implement that yourself.

Here's one (not so efficient) way with LINQ:

```
var filtered = linkedlist.Zip(linkedList.Skip(1),(current, next) => new {current, next} )
                         .Where(a => a_function(a.current, a.next))
                         .Select(a => a.current);
```

This will choose a value if the predicate matches `(value, nextValue)`. You might have to tweak the query a bit if that isn't exactly what you need.

Otherwise, go with max's solution if you need efficiency or if you have lots of filters that are based on `(node, nextNode)`.

Comment: Man, that's an ugly solution. Pretty cool if it works though, thanks. Surely there must be a nicer way, Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by max's answer, I came up with a shorter version:

```
public static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> GetNodes<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
{
    for (var node = list.First; node != null; node = node.Next)
        yield return node;
}
```

Or you could sacrifice readability for an even shorter version:

```
public static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> GetNodes<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
    => for (var node = list.First; node != null; node = node.Next) yield return node;
```